# Grunt and angularJS: change peplacement on prod server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

In my angularJS app i have such line:

```
<span class="build-version">@@appversion</span>
```

and such task in Grunt:

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: '@@appversion',
          replacement: grunt.option('build-version')?grunt.option('build-version'):'#debug'
        }
      ],
      usePrefix: false
    },
    files: [
      {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html'], dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'},
      {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'], dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'}
    ]
  }
}
```

on prod. server files are only copy-pasted from dev. server (also they have different domain name)...

is it real, and how to do not replace build version on prod server, for example according to domain name, url or etc...

only what i have on my mind is this code:

```
<span class="build-version" ng-hide="location.path().indexOf('prodserv') > -1">@@appversion</span>
```

but maybe there are more beatifull ways of doing that?

Comment: I dont see problem with showing appversion in dev version too though.

Comment: @YOU what do you mean?

Comment: I mean why you have to hide that in dev(non-prod) version.

Comment: @YOU you didn't understand: hide on prod, show on dev.

Answer (score 0):

I would depend the product's version (production,development) on a server variable and not according to the domain (or anything that is based on the client). That way, you don't even need to have any changes in your server side code, it will just expect to have a server variable that tells him what version it is and pass that info to your angular application with an ajax request when your app loads up.

If you prefer having it in the client, maybe having a config.json file that holds the correct version could be a better idea than just guessing according to the URL..